# Radius of convergence for a given sum

Tags: summation

What is a brief description of the radius of convergence? How do you find the radius of convergence for $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^i\cdot x^{-3(i-1)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root test gives 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|2^n x^{-3(n-1)}\right |} < 1$$
which can be simplified into 
$$2 |x^{-3}| < 1$$
from where you get 
$$|x|>\sqrt[3]2$$

Comment: Could you please provide a brief description of what the radius of convergence is?

Comment: @user117520 [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) is a very good source to learn it also here it is explained as well as there are few [examples](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PowerSeries.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful

Comment: It looks like the radius of convergence is usually a number that |x| has to be less than. Why is it that |x| > r allows the series to converge in this instance?

Comment: @user117520 I would say radius of convergence is an interval where value of $x$ gives converging value. It could be $|x| < r$ or $|x|>r$ but 99% of examples are $|x|>r$

Answer (score 5):

I would say that it is a geometric series. Quotient = $\frac{2}{x^3}$. Konvergens when $\frac{2}{|x^3|}<1$.

Comment: more clever approach (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start rewriting $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^i\cdot x^{-3(i-1)}=x^3~\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{2}{x^3}\Big)^i$$ in which you recognize the sum of a geometric progression. Using the standard formula, you then have $$S=\frac{2 x^3}{x^3-2}$$ I am sure that you can take from here.